# Learning curves for neural networks

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, octave

I am trying to find optimal parameters of my neural network model implemented on octave, this model is used for binary classification and 122 features (inputs) and 25 hidden units (1 hidden layer). For this I have 4 matrices/ Vectors:

```
size(X_Train): 125973 x 122
size(Y_Train): 125973 x 1
size(X_Test): 22543 x 122
size(Y_test): 22543 x 1
```

I have used 20% of the training set to generate a validation set (`XVal` and `YVal`)

```
size(X): 100778 x 122
size(Y): 100778 x 1
size(XVal): 25195 x 122
size(YVal): 25195 x 1
size(X_Test): 22543 x 122
size(Y_test): 22543 x 1
```

The goal is to generate the Learning curves of the NN. I have learned (the hard way xD) that this is **very** time consuming because I used the full size of `Xval` and `X` for this.

I don't know if there is an alternative solution for this. I am thinking to reduce the size of the training vector `X` (like 5000 samples for example), but I don't know if I can do that, or if the results will be biased since I'll only use a portion of the training set?

Bests,

Comment: Size of Y_test should be 22543 x 1.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, I made the corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of parameters above is around 3k (122*25 + 25*1), which is not huge for one example. Since the number of examples is large, you might want to use stochastic gradient descent or mini-batches instead of gradient descent.

Note that Matlab and Octave are slow in general, specially with loops.
You need to write the code which uses matrix operations rather than loops for the speed to be manageable in Matlab/Octave.

Comment: I am using the fmincg function which uses the gradient conjugate method and it's more memory efficient (I think I will read about mini-batch gradient descent and see if I can implement it)

Also, I do agree with you about what you said about loops. But I have vectorized my code.

Comment: Also what do you think about the number of hidden units I am using? is it alot?

Comment: You could try with smaller numbers  like 3 or 5, but 25 does not seem to be terribly large.

Comment: I mean, it's hard to know what to chose. I did some research and found some formulas that can help with the number of hidden units like (H = input * 70% or H= input * 90% or H= (input + output) /2). But I have 122 inputs! if I use any of these I will get terribly large hidden units. Which is why I decided to start with 25. But I will try smaller number as you have suggested!